# In Xcode 6.1. 'UIImage?' does not have a member named 'size' Error

Tags: swift, uiimage, xcode6

I'm getting an image's `Size` and used the below code. It was working perfectly fine with `Xcode 6.0.1`. After updating to `Xcode 6.1`, I'm getting  Error Like :

`'UIImage?' does not have a member named 'size'`

```
var image = UIImage(named: imageName)
let sizeOfImage = image.size
```

Is it bug with my code or Apple ? Please help me in here. TIA.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That initializer is now a failable initializer, and as such it returns an optional `UIImage`.

To quickly fix your bug just unwrap the image:

```
let sizeOfImage = image?.size
```

but I presume you will reference the `image` variable more than just once in your code, in that case I suggest using optional binding:

```
if let image = image {
    let sizeOfImage = image.size
    /// ...
    /// Use the image
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have the exact same problem with my piece of code. However, your solution does not work in mine. Any idea why?

Comment: let image = UIImage(named: imageNamed);
        
        let result = SKScrollingNode(color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: CGSizeMake(CGFloat(containerWidth), image?.size.height));

Comment: I'm getting the following error instead: Value of optional type 'CGFloat?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Antonio's answer you can use nil coalescing operator(??) to get a default size in case image initializer is failed. Here is how:

```
let size = image?.size ?? CGSizeZero
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you’re sure that the optional does contain a value, you can access its underlying value by adding an exclamation mark (!) to the end of the optional’s name. In your case: image.size!

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this:

```
    let image = UIImage(named: "photo1.png")
    let sizeOfImage = image?.size

    imageView.image = image
    imageView.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: sizeOfImage!)
```