# Swift Xcode 6.1 broke my code | Operand error

Tags: swift, compiler-errors, operand, cgfloat

So whenever I have this:

```
let result = SKScrollingNode(color: UIColor.clearColor(), size:CGSizeMake(CGFloat(containerWidth), image.size.height));
```

I get a compilation error for the image.size.height, telling me that "'UIImage?' does not have a member named 'size' although it does

Any idea what this means and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Entire code fragment:

```
class func scrollingNode(imageNamed: String, containerWidth: CGFloat) -> SKScrollingNode {
    let image = UIImage(named: imageNamed);

    let result = SKScrollingNode(color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: CGSizeMake(CGFloat(containerWidth), image.size.height));
    result.scrollingSpeed = 1.0;

    var total:CGFloat = 0.0;
    while(total < CGFloat(containerWidth) + image.size.width!) {
        let child = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: imageNamed);
        child.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
        child.position = CGPointMake(total, 0);
        result.addChild(child);
        total+=child.size.width;
    }
    return result;
```

Comment: `UIImage` has a `size`. `UIImage?` does not.

Comment: Still doesn't work: UIImage.size.height. Getting the same error, so that's not the problem

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26582035/in-xcode-6-1-uiimage-does-not-have-a-member-named-size-error

Comment: Can you please explain this bit: "Use optional chaining to unwrap the optional of image and use frame property of the UIImage." Don't quite get it.

Comment: Can you please show it in my code? You can edit it if you want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this line:

```
let image = UIImage(named: imageNamed)
```

`image` is an optional, `UIImage?`.

The error on this line:

```
let result = SKScrollingNode(color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: CGSizeMake(CGFloat(containerWidth), image.size.height));
```

can be narrowed down to this piece of code:

```
CGSizeMake(CGFloat(containerWidth), image.size.height)
```

`CGSizeMake` requires 2 `CGFloat` parameters, but the 2nd one is an optional, because `image` is an optional:

- if `image` is not nil, `image.size.height` evaluates to a CGFloat
- if `image` is nil, `image.size.height` evaluates to nil

In order to avoid that, you have 2 options:

1. make `image` a non optional by using forced unwrapping

   ```
   let image = UIImage(named: imageNamed)!
   ```

   but I do not recommend using it because if the `UIImage` creation fails, the app will crash.
2. Use optional binding:

   ```
   let image = UIImage(named: imageNamed);
   if let image = image {    
       let result = SKScrollingNode(color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: CGSizeMake(CGFloat(containerWidth), image.size.height));
       // ... rest of the code here
   }
   ```

   this is a better way to unwrap the optional, because in case it's nil, the code in the `if` statement will be skipped and no runtime error will occur.